# How to make product description in Magento Go Not Italicized

Tags: css, magento, italics, magento-go

I recently changed Magento Go templates, but there is one issue with the template I'm currently using. The entire product description is italicized, and I cannot figure out how to remove this 'feature'. I've tried searching here and on the Magento forums for an answer.

So far, I've tried italicizing the text to see if it would negate the native italicization, to no avail. I've looked at this solution:

http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=264&t=192000&rb_v=viewtopic

But it's only applicable to Magento CE, it looks like.

I've added this:

```
p.normal {font-style:normal;}
```

to the custom CSS for the template, and to the "Custom Layout Update" field on the individual product, to no avail.

**EDIT**

OK, I think I've figured out how to do this, but I have no idea how to properly format the CSS to work. I've got this far:

```
.DIV.tab-content: { p.normal {font-style:normal !important}}
```

but it's not working. I'm sure the formatting is wrong; would someone be so kind as to point me in the right direction as to how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the !important rule to your CSS.

p.normal {font-style:normal !important;}

Reference:
http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Thanks! This got me started on the right path. I'm a neophyte in CSS - Can you please tell me what exactly am I doing wrong in this CSS code?

.DIV.tab-content: { p.normal {font-style:normal !important}}

Comment: It should be formatted on one line as this:

p.normal {font-style:normal !important;}

Comment: Hi deeperDATA, thanks so much for the help. Unfortunately, that line isn't working. Is there a way to reference the "DIV.tab-content" text to instruct Magento Go that this is the only box that I want in the normal font? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can get "granular" as it is called by copying the ancestor path to a specific element. I recommend the "Web Developer Toolbar" for Firefox or Chrome. Once installed, you can use the toolbar by clicking on Information > Display Element Information and you can directly copy and paste the ancestor path into your styles sheet. Let me know if you find it.

Comment: Congrats! Please be sure to up-vote any answers that may have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had to learn a couple of things (which is always nice) to come up with this. Hope it helps someone else. Just add this to the custom CSS box of the theme that you're using:

.tab-content {font-style:normal !important;}